# Excel function in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

currently I am trying to analyze a large dataset in Excel using Power Query. To filter the rows for the desired results, I am manually adding columns to the spreadsheet to filter for results. I am using this formula for these columns:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP([@RoleApprover].Query_Approvers!E:E.1.FALSE) ). "No". "Yes")
```

My issue is that the way the dataset is structured, this results in a huge number of loaded rows making this solution not practiable. Therefore, I would like to i How can I implement this formula to Power Query to reduce the number of loaded rows.
From my understanding, I am unable to simply paste this formula into the editor. How can I create a formula with a similar result?

Edit: for clarification, I would like to remove the rows that match with another table.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Load the lookup table into a separate query, then merge the two using an inner join so you only get matching records?

Comment: As @Rory points out, you can do a LOOKUP equivalent within PQ.  You would still have to LOAD the entire table though, in the first step.  If you really want to limit what you LOAD, you would have to do that before entering PQ, by pre-processing the table that you will be loading.  Also, if you cannot pre-process the data, take a look at `Table.Buffer` to see if that might save some computation time (after you filter the table using the inner join method).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Unfortunately the problem is that I want to remove the rows that match to further analyze the rows that don't. And matching inner removes exactly the part I need.

Comment: Merging in powerquery does not remove anything  Once you expand the merge, You can filter the results to get records with a match or records without a match, your choise

Comment: It sounds like you want a left *anti*-join instead of an inner join.

Comment: Whether it includes or excludes the matching rows from the join will depend on how your tables are structured, and your code.  Data set (**as TEXT**) and a clear explanation of how you want to filter would make it much easier to help you with a solution.